# How to calculate the number of ways to choose Y items from at most X groups efficiently?

Tags: python, math, combinatorics

I don't know how to describe this concisely. Say you have X groups of items, each item in the same group is identical. All the groups have infinite size.

You want to choose Y items from the X groups completely at random, you want exactly Y items, and you can choose all from 1 group, 2 groups, 3 groups... all groups.

It is hard for me to describe so I will give a simple example. Say you want to choose 9 items from 3 groups, call these groups A, B, C.

You can choose (9A, 0B, 0C) or (0A, 9B, 0C) or (0A, 0B, 9C) or (1A, 2B, 6C)...

You can choose either from one group, from two groups, or from all groups.

The task is to find the number of ways distinct ways to partition the Y items, or the sets of counts of items from the same groups, and the composition doesn't matter.

To make it more clear, (9A, 0B, 0C) and (0A, 9B, 0C) and (0A, 0B, 9C) are treated the same, they are all counted (0, 0, 9) and there are 3 ways to obtain (0, 0, 9), 54 ways to obtain (0, 1, 8).

I tried to do it using a smart way but I got the ***WRONG*** results:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

groups = Counter()
for i in range(10):
    for k in range(j := 9 - i):
        groups[tuple(sorted((i, k, j - k)))] += 1
```

```
Counter({(1, 2, 6): 6,
         (1, 3, 5): 6,
         (2, 3, 4): 6,
         (0, 1, 8): 4,
         (0, 2, 7): 4,
         (0, 3, 6): 4,
         (0, 4, 5): 4,
         (1, 1, 7): 3,
         (1, 4, 4): 3,
         (2, 2, 5): 3,
         (0, 0, 9): 1,
         (3, 3, 3): 1})
```

So I did it the bruteforce way and iterated through all the possibilities to get the ***CORRECT*** result:

```
new_groups = Counter()
for item in product('abc', repeat=9):
    a = b = c = 0
    for e in item:
        if e == 'a':
            a += 1
        elif e == 'b':
            b += 1
        else:
            c += 1
    new_groups[tuple(sorted((a, b, c)))] += 1
```

```
Counter({(2, 3, 4): 7560,
         (1, 3, 5): 3024,
         (2, 2, 5): 2268,
         (1, 4, 4): 1890,
         (3, 3, 3): 1680,
         (1, 2, 6): 1512,
         (0, 4, 5): 756,
         (0, 3, 6): 504,
         (0, 2, 7): 216,
         (1, 1, 7): 216,
         (0, 1, 8): 54,
         (0, 0, 9): 3})
```

The result is correct, but this method is extremely inefficient, it is in exponential time, for 9 items and 3 groups it takes 19683 iterations, and 9 items 4 groups 262144 iterations!

What is a better method?

---

Perhaps I didn't make it clear but I thought the code made it pretty clear what I was after.

Now I will state it explicitly, say you have Y balls and you want to throw all of them randomly into X containers. All balls are thrown into containers, no misses (this is mathematics).

***The task is to find all sets of the counts of number of balls in the bins, which bins have the count doesn't matter, the sets are unordered (like Python `set`s), and the corresponding count of each set.***

The output should be the same as my correct but inefficient method's output. ***I am NOT trying to calculate just ONE number.***

---

The correct output is the output from the bruteforce approach. The second one.

---

I just wrote another piece of code using the bruteforce method to illustrate what the numbers mean.

```
groups2 = {}
for item in product('abc', repeat=9):
    a = b = c = 0
    for e in item:
        if e == 'a':
            a += 1
        elif e == 'b':
            b += 1
        else:
            c += 1

    key = tuple(sorted((a, b, c)))
    if key in groups2:
        groups2[key].append(''.join(item))
    else:
        groups2[key] = [''.join(item)]
```

To answer why (0, 1, 8) is 54:

```
In [43]: groups2[(0, 1, 8)]
Out[43]:
['aaaaaaaab',
 'aaaaaaaac',
 'aaaaaaaba',
 'aaaaaaaca',
 'aaaaaabaa',
 'aaaaaacaa',
 'aaaaabaaa',
 'aaaaacaaa',
 'aaaabaaaa',
 'aaaacaaaa',
 'aaabaaaaa',
 'aaacaaaaa',
 'aabaaaaaa',
 'aacaaaaaa',
 'abaaaaaaa',
 'abbbbbbbb',
 'acaaaaaaa',
 'acccccccc',
 'baaaaaaaa',
 'babbbbbbb',
 'bbabbbbbb',
 'bbbabbbbb',
 'bbbbabbbb',
 'bbbbbabbb',
 'bbbbbbabb',
 'bbbbbbbab',
 'bbbbbbbba',
 'bbbbbbbbc',
 'bbbbbbbcb',
 'bbbbbbcbb',
 'bbbbbcbbb',
 'bbbbcbbbb',
 'bbbcbbbbb',
 'bbcbbbbbb',
 'bcbbbbbbb',
 'bcccccccc',
 'caaaaaaaa',
 'caccccccc',
 'cbbbbbbbb',
 'cbccccccc',
 'ccacccccc',
 'ccbcccccc',
 'cccaccccc',
 'cccbccccc',
 'ccccacccc',
 'ccccbcccc',
 'cccccaccc',
 'cccccbccc',
 'ccccccacc',
 'ccccccbcc',
 'cccccccac',
 'cccccccbc',
 'cccccccca',
 'ccccccccb']
```

Comment: Hi. This looks like [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two). The number of 3-tuples of nonnegative integers whose sum is 9 is ((3,9)) = (3+9-1 choose 9) = (11 choose 9) = (11 choose 2) = 55.

Comment: You edited to add a section that begins with *"Perhaps I didn't make it clear"* and I confirm that the question is a lot less clear now. *"I am NOT trying to calculate just ONE number."* Okay, can you explain which numbers you are trying to calculate?

Comment: *"The output should be the same as my correct but inefficient method's output."* I see two outputs, `Counter({(1, 2, 6): 6, (1, 3, 5): 6, (2, 3, 4): 6, (0, 1, 8): 4, (0, 2, 7): 4, (0, 3, 6): 4, (0, 4, 5): 4, (1, 1, 7): 3, (1, 4, 4): 3, (2, 2, 5): 3, (0, 0, 9): 1, (3, 3, 3): 1})` and `Counter({(2, 3, 4): 7560, (1, 3, 5): 3024, (2, 2, 5): 2268, (1, 4, 4): 1890, (3, 3, 3): 1680, (1, 2, 6): 1512, (0, 4, 5): 756, (0, 3, 6): 504, (0, 2, 7): 216, (1, 1, 7): 216, (0, 1, 8): 54, (0, 0, 9): 3})`. Which one is correct?

Comment: '54 ways to obtain (0, 1, 8)' Why not 3! = 6?

Comment: Does sympy function `sympy.utilities.iterables.partitions` return what you want? https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.partitions ; or perhaps `multiset_permutations`? https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, if there are no repeated inputs (e.g. 1,2,3 OK, 1,1,3 not OK), then the number of permutations is

```
P = n! * (a1 + ... + an)! / ((a1!) * ... * (an!))
```

where n is the number of groups, and the ai are the inputs. I don't yet know how to avoid double counting when there are repeated input values.

The equation comes from counting the number of permutations of a set with duplicates, (see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038010/counting-permutation-of-duplicate-items) and multiplying by the number of ways of permuting n groups which is n!. This is valid when there are no repeated inputs because there's no way that permuting the groups can produce the same list of items.

Empirical testing appears to show that this works when only one input value is repeated, but I can't explain why.

```
P = n! * (a1 + ... + an)! / ((a1!) * ... * (an!) * D!)
```

where D is the number of times the repeated value is repeated. E.g. for 1, 2, 3, 3, D = 2, for 2, 3, 3, 3, D = 3 etc.

Further empirical testing appears to show that this works but I can't explain why.

```
P = n! * (a1 + ... + an)! / ((a1!) * ... * (an!) * D1! * ... *Dm!)
```

where there are m distinct input values which occur Di times. E.g. for 1, 2, 3, 3, [D1, D2, D3] = [1, 1, 2], for 2, 3, 3, 3, [D1, D2] = [1, 3].

While this isn't proof, it does appear to work. 7^11 = 1977326743.

```
7 : 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 
462 : 0 0 0 0 0 1 10 
2310 : 0 0 0 0 0 2 9 
6930 : 0 0 0 0 0 3 8 
13860 : 0 0 0 0 0 4 7 
19404 : 0 0 0 0 0 5 6 
11550 : 0 0 0 0 1 1 9 
103950 : 0 0 0 0 1 2 8 
277200 : 0 0 0 0 1 3 7 
485100 : 0 0 0 0 1 4 6 
291060 : 0 0 0 0 1 5 5 
207900 : 0 0 0 0 2 2 7 
970200 : 0 0 0 0 2 3 6 
1455300 : 0 0 0 0 2 4 5 
970200 : 0 0 0 0 3 3 5 
1212750 : 0 0 0 0 3 4 4 
138600 : 0 0 0 1 1 1 8 
1663200 : 0 0 0 1 1 2 7 
3880800 : 0 0 0 1 1 3 6 
5821200 : 0 0 0 1 1 4 5 
5821200 : 0 0 0 1 2 2 6 
23284800 : 0 0 0 1 2 3 5 
14553000 : 0 0 0 1 2 4 4 
19404000 : 0 0 0 1 3 3 4 
5821200 : 0 0 0 2 2 2 5 
29106000 : 0 0 0 2 2 3 4 
12936000 : 0 0 0 2 3 3 3 
831600 : 0 0 1 1 1 1 7 
11642400 : 0 0 1 1 1 2 6 
23284800 : 0 0 1 1 1 3 5 
14553000 : 0 0 1 1 1 4 4 
52390800 : 0 0 1 1 2 2 5 
174636000 : 0 0 1 1 2 3 4 
38808000 : 0 0 1 1 3 3 3 
87318000 : 0 0 1 2 2 2 4 
174636000 : 0 0 1 2 2 3 3 
43659000 : 0 0 2 2 2 2 3 
2328480 : 0 1 1 1 1 1 6 
34927200 : 0 1 1 1 1 2 5 
58212000 : 0 1 1 1 1 3 4 
174636000 : 0 1 1 1 2 2 4 
232848000 : 0 1 1 1 2 3 3 
349272000 : 0 1 1 2 2 2 3 
52390800 : 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 
2328480 : 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 
34927200 : 1 1 1 1 1 2 4 
23284800 : 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 
174636000 : 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 
87318000 : 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 
Total 1977326743 :
```

Comment: @Stef I wrote my own brute force counting program and confirmed the OPs numbers. (0, 1, 8) -> 54, not 55, sorry.

Comment: How do you use this to solve the problem?

Comment: @KellyBundy Counter({(2, 3, 4): 7560, can be solved P = (3!*9!) / (2! * 3! * 4!) = 7560 etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [stars and bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two).

The number of 3-tuples of nonnegative integers whose sum is 9 is ((3,9)) = (3+9-1 choose 9) = (11 choose 9) = (11 choose 2) = 55.

More generally the number of k-tuples of nonnegative integers whose sum is n is ((k,n)) = (n+k-1 choose n).

```py
from math import comb

def number_of_ways_to_choose_n_items_from_k_groups(k, n):
    return comb(n+k-1, n)
```

Comment: Already revision 1 of the question showed their *Counter* as "the correct result".

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @[Simon Goater](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20460267/simon-goater) is correct and so I accepted it.

I was able to write an efficient program to calculate the numbers based on the formula in said answer. And I have written another bruteforce approach to verify the correctness of the smart approach.

```
import math
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product
from typing import Collection, Generator, List, Set, Tuple


def partition(
    target: int, limit: int, prefix: list = None
) -> Generator[List[int], None, None]:
    if prefix is None:
        prefix = []

    if limit == 2:
        for i in range(target):
            yield prefix + [i, target - i]
    else:
        for i in range(target):
            yield from partition(target - i, limit - 1, prefix + [i])


def unique_partitions(target: int, limit: int) -> Set[Tuple[int]]:
    return {tuple(sorted(e)) for e in partition(target, limit)}


def counter_expand(values: Collection[int]) -> Counter:
    result = Counter()
    for n in values:
        for i in range(2, n + 1):
            result[i] += 1

    return result


def balls_in_bins(balls: int, bins: int) -> Counter:
    assert balls >= bins >= 2
    result = {}
    for config in unique_partitions(balls, bins):
        numerator = counter_expand((bins, balls))
        denominator = counter_expand(config) + counter_expand(Counter(config).values())
        result[config] = math.prod((numerator - denominator).elements()) // math.prod(
            (denominator - numerator).elements()
        )

    return Counter(dict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1])))


def balls_in_bins_bruteforce(balls: int, bins: int) -> Counter:
    result = Counter()
    for item in product(range(bins), repeat=balls):
        counts = [0] * bins
        for i in item:
            counts[i] += 1

        result[tuple(sorted(counts))] += 1

    return result
```

```
In [45]: balls_in_bins(9, 3)
Out[45]:
{(0, 2, 7): 216,
 (1, 4, 4): 1890,
 (1, 3, 5): 3024,
 (1, 2, 6): 1512,
 (2, 2, 5): 2268,
 (3, 3, 3): 1680,
 (0, 0, 9): 3,
 (0, 3, 6): 504,
 (2, 3, 4): 7560,
 (0, 1, 8): 54,
 (0, 4, 5): 756,
 (1, 1, 7): 216}

In [46]: balls_in_bins_bruteforce(9, 3) == balls_in_bins(9, 3)
Out[46]: True

In [47]: balls_in_bins_bruteforce(9, 4) == balls_in_bins(9, 4)
Out[47]: True

In [48]: 4**9
Out[48]: 262144

In [49]: 5**9
Out[49]: 1953125

In [50]: balls_in_bins_bruteforce(9, 5) == balls_in_bins(9, 5)
Out[50]: True
```

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed because I still don't know what was the problem that you were trying to solve :(

Comment: @Stef My take on the question is that he wants the breakdown of counts like those shown in the question and in my answer.